# Upload large files using Retrofit

Tags: android, http, retrofit, file-transfer

I am currently using Retrofit in my project for general HTTP request and for uploading files. For uploading files, I am using `Multipart` requests. So, small files transfer hasn't turned out to be a problem but it is my project's requirements that file size can go as high as 1 GB.

Further, it is acceptable that the complete file, if doesn't reach in one go may complete when there is Network and other conditions are met. This also means that I need some system/strategy to upload part of a file and next time resume from the part where I left.

How can I achieve the same on Android? What would be the considerations or protocol I may need to follow to achieve it from the server side(if anyone knows)?

Comment: Did you find a solution bro ?